# Keyboard between the alphabetic and the numeric one disappears with Block Num

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, configuration

I decided to update my version to 18.04 when I started to have problems of misconfiguration of the keyboard on the 16 version I had (characters like $ % & / ( ) = ? * and so on got completely misplaced on the keyboard layout).

I tried to solve following the indications I found in other questions here and in other places. It didn't work.

I decided to take the system update I had delayed for a long time (yes, I'm a little bit lazy :-))) )

After the update the signs were back to their right places (great), but another phenomenon appeared: now, when I have activated the "block num" to have numbers and arithmetic operations in the right top numeric keyboard, the little section of the keyboard, between the numeric and the alphabetic ones, with the keys <kbd>Start</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, <kbd>Insert</kbd>, <kbd>Supress</kbd> and the four direction arrows, go completely inactive. Pressing those keys seems to have absolutely no effect. They come back to their functions when I deactivate the "Block num" (so then I have the direction arrow keys, but also the same function on the 2, 4, 6 and 8 keys on the numeric keyboard).

Please, can anybody tell me how I may fix this problem?

Comment: Just an addicional coment, as it could be relevant (I'm not sure): my local keyboard language layout is Catalan, not English, and the keyboard is a generic 105 keys one)

Comment: Does this happen in the terminal or in the GUI? If the latter, then Xorg or Wayland?

Comment: It happens in all the applications you may write text. With the block num activated, the arrow, Start and End keys become completely inactive.